# Got problems on using stl between dlls

Tags: c++, windows, dll, stl

I've got a vector (or string) in a dll, is it safe to modify it in another dll through its reference or pointer, like push a new member to the vector or change the string's value? Somehow sometimes crash occurs when I do this and I don't know why.

If I just read it in another dll, using const pointer or reference, is it absolutely safe?

How about using stlport? Is it safer?

Answer (score 2):

If you modify an STL container, delete or add new element to it, it usually involves allocating/deallocating memory. If it happens that you allocate some memory using an allocator residing in one DLL, and then deallocate the memory in a different DLL - using another allocator, living in the other DLL - then you may get into trouble. I think this is probably what you are experiencing.

One possible solution is to encapsulate your STL container in your class, and access functions of the STL container via functions of that class. The idea is that you have implementation of the class in one DLL and whenever you manipulate that object (and so the STL container), you only use one C++ allocator.

If you manipulate a `const` object (as you say: 'read only' access) created in one DLL in another DLL then it doesn't involve C++ allocator, so it should be safe.

Answer (score 1):

Accessing stl containers from multiple DLLs is safe (both reading and writing), provided both DLLs use the same STL variant. Visual Studio provides two STL variants, a release variant and a debug variant with additional checks (enabled in Debug mode or by defining _SECURE_SCL). These two variants are not compatible! Mixing the two modes (e.g. because one DLL was compiled in debug mode and the other in release mode) can lead to mysterious crashes, because the container sizes differ between the two variants.

See https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/524141/serious-bug-when-using-secure-scl-0-c for more information.